# Style the Title Attribute for HTML Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone show me how to style the title attribute for an html textarea. I have tried [this jfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/tDQWN/) but it seems not to be working.I am using the chrome browser The code is below.

```html
<li>
   <label for="description">Nature of Visit</label>
   <textarea class = "description" name="description" id="description" placeholder="required" required title="Must be at least 8 characters."></textarea>
</li>
```

the css code is here.

```css
textarea[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

Comment: Textarea seem don't have a title attribute (see here https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html) so you cant style it with css.

Comment: [This](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-hide-default-title-when-using-tooltip/22762) answer may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You cant style default title

For example you can use bootstrap:

```
<textarea data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="My title">

</textarea>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jqueryui Tooltip for **Customizable, themeable tooltips, replacing native tooltips.**

HTML:

```
<p>Hover the field to see the tooltip.</p>
<textarea class = "description" name="description" id="description" placeholder="required" required title="Must be at least 8 characters."></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
});
```

[See JsFiddle !](http://jsfiddle.net/buvndnbk/)

also [JQuery UI Reference](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

JS, CSS References:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: works in the jfiddle site but cannot get it to function for my site. the function is placed at the top of the page.

Comment: Have you included External Resources ? [jquery-ui.css](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css) , [jquery-1.10.2.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js) , [jquery-ui.js](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js)

Comment: Ok, did not add that.Thank you.

Comment: inserted this lines into the header file but it does not work.   <script language="javascript" type='text/javascript' src="js/query-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.ui.css"></link>

Comment: i suggest to use original CDN URLs instead of path "js/" you used in src..
**please add these lines to header:** 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> , <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> , <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

**also i have added references to my answer**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only css you can wrap everything in a div and trigger the show of the tooltip element with CSS.

You can then customise the tooltip element as you like (font, colors, position).

The container has to be position relative for the absolute element to get the correct positioning. 
More about CSS positioning https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position

Html

```
  <div class="input">
    <h4>Hover me</h4>
    <span>this is the tooltip</span>
  </div>
```

Css

```
*{
  font-family:Helvetica;
}

.input{
  position:relative;
}
.input span{
  position:absolute;
  top:1.5em;
  left:1.5em;
  background:red;
  color:white;
  padding:0.4em;
  opacity:0;
  transition:all 1s;
}

.input:hover span{  
  opacity:1;
}
```